# ubuntu asks for fsck on boot everytime

Tags: error-handling

well, this error log is not mine but I got the same a dozen times for the last few days. the last time it happened I was running virtualbox and I suddenly got a error I couldn't run any system then I tried to reboot, nothing has happened and I used ctrl + alt + del (once that my painel power button wasn't working either)... everytime it happens my computer just work good for a quite while without any trouble.

I've seen this problem a lot while I was looking for a way to fix it, and I do really know that's problematic ask the same thing a lot of times. There's rules that I should probably read somewhere but for now I just want to fix that thing... I'm kind of newbie and I can't just reinstall my distro once that I have no way to save my files

/dev/sda6 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda6: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda6 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

edit: gsmartcontrol test is all okay

Comment: On the surface it sounds like your disk is going bad. What make, model and year is it?

Comment: it's a western digital green power... I bought this year when ubuntu 19.04 was released

Comment: I found similar issues: https://community.wd.com/t/silent-data-corruption-on-green-ssd-wds120g2g0a-00jh30-with-linux/229202